# Android Threads: FinalizerWatchDogDaemon

Tags: android, performance

What are these android threads? Are they system threads? It seems Thread 2 cause's one of my activities to periodically not be GC'd. I would like to understand if these have something to do with my app or if their system threads to not worry about. Thanks in Advance.

1). FinalizerDaemon,
2). FinalizerWatchDogDaemon

[image: DDMS - THREADS]